# Using Google Signin Button in Fragment

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am following https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin to include Google sign in my android application. But the only difference is i am using Signin button in fragment instead of activity. So when i try to login user by clicking signin button, i am not able to login. When i debug the code, i got to know Google authentication is failed in onActivityResult method.

**WelcomeActivity.java**

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "WelcomeActivity";


    private ViewPager welcomeViewPager;
    private WelcomePagerAdapter welcomePagerAdapter;
    @BindView(R.id.skip) TextView skip;
    @BindView(R.id.login) TextView login;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    finishOnboarding();
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                //updateUI(user);
            }
        };

        welcomeViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.welcome_viewPager);
        welcomePagerAdapter = new WelcomePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        welcomeViewPager.setAdapter(welcomePagerAdapter);

        InkPageIndicator inkPageIndicator = (InkPageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        inkPageIndicator.setViewPager(welcomeViewPager);

     }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }


    private void finishOnboarding() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

And My Fragment, where i put Google sigin button is

```
public class OverviewFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
    private static final String TAG = "OverviewFragment";
    private static final int GOOGLE_RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
    private static final int TWITTER_RC_SIGN_IN = 140;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    @BindView(R.id.sign_in_button) SignInButton mGoogleSigninButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_overview, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                    finishOnboarding();
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                //updateUI(user);
            }
        };
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(),this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,gso)
                .build();
        mGoogleSigninButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent signinIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(signinIntent, GOOGLE_RC_SIGN_IN);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_RC_SIGN_IN){
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                handleGoogleAuthentication(account);
            } else {
                //Google Login Failed
                Log.d(TAG, "Google Login Failed "+result.getSignInAccount()+"Status is "+result.getStatus());
            }
        } else if (requestCode == TWITTER_RC_SIGN_IN) {
            //mTwitterLoginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        } else {
            //callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
        }
    }


    private void handleGoogleAuthentication(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    //Save Credentials in Google Smart Lock
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    //updateUser(user);
                } else {
                    //
                    Log.d(TAG, "Login failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
    private void finishOnboarding() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Can some one tell me where i am doing wrong? Thank you. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4):

Please try this code and working for me

In onCreate of your activity

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestServerAuthCodegetString(R.string.default_web_client_id)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
            .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Override the `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == mController.RC_GET_TOKEN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
     }
}
```

`onClick` of Google plus login button

```
   try {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GET_TOKEN);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is mController?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with Jetpack's Navigation component and Kotlin is stated below. Here no need to add any code in activity:

```
class SignInFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_signin) {

    companion object {
        const val GOOGLE_SIGN_IN = 1903
    }

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        auth = Firebase.auth
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(requireContext(), getGSO())
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener { signIn() }
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)!!
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.idToken!!)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                //handle error
            }
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(idToken: String) {
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(idToken, null)
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity()) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                   //handle success
                } else {
                    //handle error
                }
            }
    }

    private fun getGSO(): GoogleSignInOptions {
        return  GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
    }
}
```

Sign in button in xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:buttonSize="wide">
```